# How to return primary key of updated records when using @Query in JPA with Spring Boot

Tags: jpa, spring-boot

I would like to know whether it is possible to return the primary keys of the records updated by an update query using @Query annotation with Spring boot and JPA

Answer (score 0):

Not by the same repository method that performs the update. It only returns void or the number of updated records.

You could create another query method, with the same *where* conditions as your update query, which returns only the id attribute. Then you only have to call it just before calling the update query.